# Auth0 react-native login with email and password fails. How do I fix it?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, authentication, auth0

I have followed the instructions described in [HERE](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native/00-login#integrate-auth0-in-your-application).

This is my `android/app/build.gradle`

```
....

 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.someapp.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [auth0Domain: "someapp.us.auth0.com", auth0Scheme: ${applicationId}"]
    }
.....
```

This is how my `AppDelegate.mm` looks like

[image: AppDelegate.mm]

When a user tries to log in or register, this error message `[a0.credential_manager.invalid: No credentials were found in the store.]` is returned. The user object from the `useAuth0` hook is `null` so are credentials from the `getCredentials()` method.

What does the error message mean and how can I fix this?

`App.tsx`

```
import { Auth0Provider } from 'react-native-auth0';
import { Config } from './config';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={Config.AUTH0_DOMAIN}
      clientId={Config.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
    >
       <RestOfApp/>
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`Login.tsx`

```
import { useAuth0 } from 'react-native-auth0';


const Login = () => {

  const { authorize, user, getCredentials, error } =
    useAuth0();

  const onLogin = async () => {
    try {
      await authorize();
      const creds = await getCredentials();

      console.log(error, creds);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } 
  };

  return (
  
      <View>
    
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            onLogin();
          }}
         title="Login"
        />
    
      </View>
 
  );
};

export default Login;
```

#### Environment

- Version of this Auth0 library used: 2.17.1
- React Native (0.71.3)